# Facebook Messenger bot Publish error

Tags: python, django, facebook, bots

My Facebook messenger bot was working perfectly, but as soon as I started the `Publish` process (making the bot available for everyone) my bot stopped responding.

There is no error in my code or on the server, and the webhook is connected. I tested my webhook connection and got a `{"success":true}` response in `terminal`.

Once I started the `Publish` process I also started receiving these error messages from Facebook:

> Your Webhooks subscription for callback URL .... has not been accepting updates for at least 16 minutes

Somehow, Facebook managed to mess up my application, which was working perfectly fine, and now I cannot even get in contact with Facebook, because there is no way to contact them.

By the way, my code is written in Python and I have used Django

Comment: It's a nice story but I don't see how anyone is supposed to be able to help debug here.

Comment: Sayse what do you mean by "it's a nice story", are you trying to be funny?

Comment: Perhaps it came across the wrong way. What I meant was all you've told us is something that works locally doesn't work when published without anything for anyone to help debug.

Comment: Its works locally, but it worked on facebook as well, because whenever i added someone as a tester role or developer role, they were able to interact with the messenger bot, but as soon as i started the publish process, the messenger bot just suddenly stopped responding. I have no idea what the problem is? And the reason why i created this post, was to see if anyone else has encountered a similar problem? And I have no other place to search for help, because facebook doesn't help you at all.

Comment: As it stands though, I don't see where anyone could help here. You'll need to start with looking into logging, and any differences between builds (env vars etc). Your problem as written is too broad and vague which is where a [mcve] would help

Comment: I understand what you mean, but look at it from my perspective, I have absolutely no idea why the bot is not responding, nothing in logs, nothing wrong with the application at all! No compile errors whatsoever! It may be because facebook's developer options is in beta? I dont know.... I can't explain to you what the problem is, when I don't even know what the problem is....

Comment: Did you Bot get disabled?  If so, you have to send a post request to reenable it. Very confusing.

Comment: curl -ik -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/subscribed_apps?access_token=[token]

Comment: Matthew Fisher thank you so much! It was disabled, without any message or notification about it. Your terminal command fixed it! :)